# How can I continue the if from where i last picked of

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I've been working on chat bot lately which questions people about their name and age and describes their generation using if like this:

```
     if (age >= 57 && age <= 75) {
                System.out.println("Oh so you're a baby boomer)");
                String boomer = in.nextLine();

but when I try to continue the questions it cuts off.




 System.out.println("Hello my name is ADA what's your name? ");
        String Name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What a delightful name, How old are you dear?");
        int age = in.nextInt();
   if (age<=18){
              System.out.println("Oh your younger than I excpected come back when you are older dear)  ");   
              
        if (age >= 57 && age <= 75) {
            System.out.println("Oh so your a baby boomer)");
            String baby = in.nextLine();
            
            if (age>=42 && age <=56){
                System.out.println("oh so your from Generation x");
            String x = in.nextLine();
            
            if (age>=21 && age <=41){
            System.out.println("Oh so your from Generation Y");
            String Y= in.nextLine();
```

*I dont know what i did wrong so I did place a scanner so that it would go to the next question but it seems that it stays where it is.*

Comment: You are not using proper `if` statement syntax.

Comment: It would be more proper to calculate from a person's birthdate. Using their age means that your program will be wrong in a few years.

Comment: please format the code correctly, this will help you will find you are nesting the ifs instead of evaluating each of them

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this so it will actually compile

```
        System.out.println("Hello my name is ADA what's your name? ");
        String Name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What a delightful name, How old are you dear?");
        int age = in.nextInt();
        if (age <= 18) {
            System.out.println("Oh your younger than I excpected come back when you are older dear)  ");
        } else if (age >= 57 && age <= 75) {
            System.out.println("Oh so your a baby boomer)");
            String baby = in.nextLine();

        } else if (age >= 42 && age <= 56) {
            System.out.println("oh so your from Generation x");
            String x = in.nextLine();

        } else if (age >= 21 && age <= 41) {
            System.out.println("Oh so your from Generation Y");
            String Y = in.nextLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mind posting your complete code to take a look?
It seems that the conditions are not nested properly, so the control flow is not same as what you expect it be.
for example,
if age == 54
The first condition would be false:

`if (age >= 57 && age <= 75) {`

and I don't see any else condition to handle the cases for that.

Try something like this:

```
if (age >= 57 && age <= 75) {
  ... action for this age range
} else if(age < 57) {
  ... action for when age is lesser than 57
} else {
  ... action for when age is greater than 75
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, your code is a little mess. I re-arranged it and everything works fine:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello my name is ADA what's your name? ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What a delightful name, How old are you dear?");
    int age = in.nextInt();
    if (age<=18){
        System.out.println("Oh your younger than I expected come back when you are older dear");
    }
    if (age>=21 && age <=41){
      System.out.println("Oh so your from Generation Y");
      boolean bn = in.nextBoolean();          
      if (bn == false) {
        System.out.println("Fine suit yourself ");
      } 
      else if (bn == true) {
        System.out.println("Did you workout today?");
        String yourself = in.nextLine();
      }
    }
    if (age>=42 && age <=56){
        System.out.println("oh so your from Generation x");
        String x = in.nextLine();
    }
    if (age >= 57 && age <= 75) {
        System.out.println("Oh so your a baby boomer");
        String baby = in.nextLine();
    }
  }
}
```

At the end of every if case you are asking the user to input data `in.nextLine()` that is not being used, so you should consider either removing it or use the data.